# yii how to put link to another form in cgridview

Tags: yii, cgridview

how to put link in the classcode to proceed to another form

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'classlist-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
        **'classCode'**,
        'classDesc',
        array(
            'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
        ),
    ),
)); ?>
```

Comment: What you meant by link to another form. Give some explanation what you want

Answer (score 1):

You can use a clink column

```
'columns'=>array(
   .....
    array(
      'class'=>'CLinkColumn',
      'label'=>'your_attribute',
      'url'=>'your_controller/your_action&id='.$model->your_attribute,
     'header'=>'your_column_header'
  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Hii you can also use this

```
array(
   'name' => 'you_field',
   'header' => 'label',
   'type' => 'raw',
   'value' => 'CHtml::link($data->you_field,Yii::app()->createUrl("controller/action",array("param"=>$data->you_field)),array("target"=>"_blank"))',
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi use this code,

```
 array(
                            'header' =>Your Header Name,
                            'value' => '$data->subject->subject_name."  -  ".$data->subject->subject_code',
'url' => 'Yii::app()->createUrl("core/subject/deleteelective", array("id"=>$data->electivesubjectid))',
                            'htmlOptions' => array('width' => '45%'),
                        ),
```